# So, is there any way that I can use an alias, while still invoking the getter of it's reference?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, alias, getter

I have an `entity` object that has a property `prop`. `prop` has a getter that gets called every time I invoke `entity.prop`, as intended. However, if I was to make an alias such as `let myProp = entity.prop`, I would hope that the getter continues to be invoked every time I call `myProp`, as `entity.prop` is not a raw data type and should be passed by reference. However, this is not the case. The getter is never invoked when calling `myProp`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Okay, yes, but you don't want that. Instead, just pass `entity` around, as objects are "pass by reference".

Concerning the no: Variables always hold values. The expression `entity.prop` evaluates to a value (by executing the getter), that it is a getter is completely unknown to the user (it is *transparent*). Therefore when you evaluate `myEntity` the engine simply does not know where the value came from and that it came from a getter.

Please never ever ever use the *Yes* shown here:

```
 with({ get myProp() { return Date.now(); /* or entity.prop */ }) {
   console.log(myPro, myProp, myProp);
 }
```